# Create a VS / R# rule to enforce usage of 'this' when calling non-static methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-8.2

On my current project I **have** to call all non static methods with the `this.` prefix.

For example:

```
public void Test(){
    //wrong call
    DoIt();
    //Right call
    this.DoIt();
}
public void DoIt(){
    return "yeah";
}
```

Now R# says (and it is right) that when I type `this.`, it is a redundant qualifier.

So I switched of that rule, but  I want to go one step further: can I create a rule in R# (or VS2013) itself to give me a warning when I don't use `this.` in calling non-static methods?

Comment: Do you use StyleCop`? There is a rule to that effect.

Comment: No I don't, but I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Stylecop is a "good code formatting" checker which is used at Microsoft (but not owned by them as I understand). It IS a pain sometimes, but overall I like it when a few rules are disabled (spellchecking, hungarian notation detection)

Comment: Excellent! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use https://stylecop.codeplex.com/, which checks this and many other formatting issues. 
It can be somewhat anal sometimes, so it might be a good idea to disable certain rules like spellchecking (the dictionary is limited and adding words is costing a lot of time) and hungarian notation checking (I feel every second variable is hungarian for stylecop....)

Additionally, I would recommend to use special comments like autogenerated to turn off stylecop for code generated by tools (like entity framework code first migrations)

http://shishkin.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/stylecop-how-to-ignore-generated-code/